# How to join students and assessments tables into one View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

In my SQL database, I want to connect two tables in one View only, the first contains the Student's information and the second one contains the Assessments. The problem is in that, that when I create the View I don't get the assessment in Math subject for each student. If I haven't written any assessments in the subject table I don't get any information in the View. I want to make it, that if there are not assessments just to write NULL.

So, if you want to see the problem directly here is a video, that i've published in youtube.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdtLfLF2SFk&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have used equi-join. Try using left join to attain what you want

Comment: Mani, after i did change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, (it made itself to LEFT OUTER JOIN), and i executed the table, that moment i thought that my problem is solved, but now when i try so write some assessment in the view, in some of the subjects, i do get the following error: "Data has changed since the Results pane was last retrieved.Do you want to save your changes now?" And when i do press Yes, It says "No row was updated.". Finally my problem is not solved again :( Please tell me what else i can do, cause i am trying to fix that for about 6 days already. Thanks again.

Comment: what database are you using. are you using any tool?? And did you use as student left join assessment.

Comment: Well, i am using SQL server studio managment express, as you see in the video, for tools, i use only Qt with C++, what tools do you mean?

Comment: I am begginer in the Sql databases Mani, so i don't know the correct syntax of "as student left join assessment". I will write my simple query and please do the change however you want and rewrite my query: SELECT  dbo.UserInfo.Name, dbo.UserInfo.LastName, dbo.Subjects.Math, dbo.Subjects.Art, dbo.Subjects.Rockets
FROM         dbo.UserInfo LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Subjects ON dbo.UserInfo.ID_User = dbo.Subjects.ID_Subject. Thanks in advance.